# KB4025252 is offered even though it's already installed

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, internet-explorer-11

Windows Update keeps offering KB4025252 (Cumulative security update for Internet Explorer: July 11, 2017) over and over and over again - even though it's already installed.

We've seen this on two PCs so far, both Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Looks like we're not the only ones seeing this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c713cd6-87ba-4908-bc06-fef248dcbd26/kb4025252-security-update-for-internet-explorer-11-install-multiple-times?forum=w7itprosecurity.

Is there a solution to this, other than waiting for Microsoft to fix yet another botched Windows Update?

Comment: I assume you have restarted?  Have you tried to uninstall the patch then reinstall it?

Comment: Same issue here. Install, repeat, etc. For now we have declined it in WSUS. That should work but I ended up hiding it for now on my machine.

Comment: We can confirm that restarting did not help in our environment.

Comment: According to the KB, "The fixes included in this Security Update for Internet Explorer 4025252 are also included in the July 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup. Installing either the Security Update for Internet Explorer or the Security Monthly Quality Rollup installs the fixes that are resolved in this update."  So, if you have that installed it might be safe to decline this update after all.

Comment: install the quality rollup, that includes all fixes so here the IE update is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a benign bug by Microsoft.  Since the changes are already included in the July Security Monthly Quality Rollup ([KB4025341](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4025252/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-july-11-2017)), the patch wasn't detecting that the patch was no longer required:

> The fixes included in this Security Update for Internet Explorer 4025252 are also included in the July 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup. Installing either the Security Update for Internet Explorer or the Security Monthly Quality Rollup installs the fixes that are resolved in this update.

Per [this forum thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c713cd6-87ba-4908-bc06-fef248dcbd26/kb4025252-security-update-for-internet-explorer-11-install-multiple-times?forum=w7itprosecurity), Microsoft released an updated version of the patch via WSUS if you want to perform a manual synchronization.  Otherwise, you'll pick it up on your next scheduled sync.

I tested it myself, and it's no longer showing up on my PC as a necessary patch.

Comment: Good spot.  I'll check this out at work tomorrow.

Comment: WSUS downloaded the revised update, KB4025252 last night.  Problem solved :).